# How to upload PHP and MySQL into a webserver

Tags: php, mysql, upload, webserver

I am developing a site in vertigoserver. Now I need to test the webpage in webserver.

I am using the webserver Host-Europe VirtualServer 3.0.

1. Now what are the steps I need to upload the PHP pages?
2. What is the software needed to upload MySQL queries?
3. Are there any tutorials or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like basic stuff, but I'll give you some pointers!

Upload the pages with an FTP client or similar. If you have shell access, tools like [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) can make this easier.

You've probably got some sort of web based front end for MySQL like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/docs.php) - this will let you upload and restore a database dump. If you have shell access, or if the MySQL server is open to the Internet, you can pipe the dump into the MySQL command line client, for example,

```
mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p<password> mydatabase < dump.mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you got a virtual machine and don't know how to upload stuff? This has been discussed in Host-Europe forums for a while. If you don't know the basics you probably don't want to run a server on your own. If you don't know how to use Linux don't start with a machine which can get you in a lot of trouble. A hosting package is probably better you at the moment.

The problem I have is you didn't specify what OS you have. If you're using Linux with [Plesk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesk) you want to activate FTP, etc. If you are using Linux without Plesk you want to upload the PHP files with [WinSCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP) and over SSH ([SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)).

If you are running Windows with Plesk use FTP. If not, you should install an FTP server on the machine.

Regarding the MySQL stuff you're probably best off installing a webfrontend for MySQL.

!DON'T FORGET TO SECURE IT!